# How to show that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}$ converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

Given the series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}
$$
I have to show that the series converges both absolutely and uniformly on the real axis. I have shown without trouble that the series converges absolutely on the real axis but I am struggling to show that it converges uniformly on the real axis.

I know that a series converges uniformly if the partial sums $\{s_n\}$ where $s_n := \sum_{k=1}^n f_k$ converges uniformly but how do I prove that the partial sums converges uniformly? Do I have to use the definition of uniformly convergence saying that

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall x \in X \forall n \in \mathbb{N} : n \geq N \Rightarrow |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon 
$$
where $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions on the set $X$ with the function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}
$. Can you guide me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Answer (score 3):

Use The M test of weistrass with $a_n=\frac{1}{n^3}$

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: So by recalling that $ - 1 \leq sin(nx) \leq 1$ we have that $\frac{|sin(nx)|}{n^3} \leq \frac{1}{n^3}$ and here we know from real analysis that $\frac{1}{n^3}$ converges, so the M-test of Weierstrass gives us that the series $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^3}
$$ converges both absolutely and uniformly?

Comment: Can anyone verify if the above I have done is correct? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @Mathias It's correct !.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was apparently pretty easy.